# Trying to set up android development in eclipse -- can't find the SDK location?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

I am trying to set up eclipse with android on a new laptop and am downloading the android SDK through Help -> Install New Software where it is invisibly installed somewhere, but I then need to tell eclipse where it has been installed.

Best I can tell from googling around is the plugins folder, unfortunately I do not seem to have a plugins folder. Does anyone know how I can find out this mystery location?

Comment: Just a heads up (in case you didn't know) eclipse is no longer supported by Google for Android dev and Android Studios is the official IDE. Not that you can't do eclipse obviously but the support is shifting away.

Comment: I think I'll do that, I finally got eclipse set up on my second computer (Bugged eclipse updates have my original laptop's version of eclipse in an unrecoverable state it seems) and now I encounter new bugs trying to set up a Galaxy S5 emulator. Thanks.

Comment: I fought shifting to Android Studio for months during beta but now that it is the official/stable release I couldn't imagine having to go back to eclipse. Well worth taking the time to transition if you are focusing on Android dev and not general java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using windows, you can directly entered in the sdk directory by writing the below location into your address bar,

C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

USERNAME=Administrator or the username of your computer,

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly where it was.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I upvoted but didn't accept, that should be fixed now, thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

The SDK folder should be in Users\yourName\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

You might want to enable hidden folders or just manually typing in the directory through the command prompt.

I am assuming you are using Windows.

Answer (score 0):

If you use mac, you can type the command below which will display all instances of java installed.

> sudo find / -name java

Answer (score 0):

If you are running windows, you might have eclipse installed in C:\program files folder.  It should have a sub directory of plugins.
If you followed these directions:  http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html which tells you to download a .zip file and install ADT via the method you described. You know ADT is installed when it shows up in your eclipse window menu.  Keep in mind that Android Studio is the favored IDE by Google now.